# Find $f(c)$ given the graph of $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I am given a graph of the derivative of some function and asked to find $f(c)$.
I can't explain it well without the graph, so here is the image of the problem:

[image]

First of all, should't the point labeled on the graph as $(3,2)$ be $(2,3)$?
Second, wouldn't $f(6)$ be the integral from $0$ to $6$ of the graph?
If so, then I have the area of the square $(3*2)$ plus the first triangle $(3)$ minus the third triangle $(1)$, giving me an answer of $8$.

Is this incorrect?  Why do I need to know that $f(0)=7$?

Comment: Consider a simpler exercise.  Find f(1).  Note how you do it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial. I have already made an [edit] to this post to include MathJaX. Please check if I did not change the meaning of the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The point labelled $(3,2)$ should be labelled $(2,3)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus:$$\int_0^6f'(x)\ \mathrm{d}x=f(6)-f(0)$$ So $f(6)=\int_0^6f'(x)\ \mathrm{d}x+f(0)$. To find the integral we must find the area above the x-axis and the curve and subtract the area below the x-axis and the curve. $$\int_0^6f'(x)\ \mathrm{d}x=6+3-1=8$$ So $f(6)=8+7=15.$

Comment: And yes the point should be labeled as $\left(2,3\right)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$
\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx = f(b) \color{red}{- f(a)}
$$

Comment: It is common to forget this bit about subtracting the initial value since, when we integrate polynomials and use the usual antiderivative, $f(0)$ always happens to be zero.